# Responsive website for mobile screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm quite new to web development for mobile devices, mostly used to developping for desktop screens. I'm currently writing again a website code to make it responsive with Bootstrap 3. I have issues with font sizes that are very small once on a mobile phone screen whereas they are good on my desktop computer screen (see image below for a Samsung xcover3 screen : 480x800).

Is there a way to make it better without making font sizes bigger? This solution would produce extremely large font sizes on desktop screens, which is not satisfying either...

[image]

Comment: wiltomap, do you have this meta-tag in the `<head>`: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0  />`

Comment: Oops! I had a typing error inside the `meta` tag... Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us a link to a codepen, jsfiddle etc so people can edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Media Queries.
Add this MQ properties at your custom CSS.

```
@media screen and ( max-width : 991px ) {
       .example {font-size:20px; {
        }
}

@media screen and ( max-width : 768px ) {
        .example {font-size:20px; {
        }
}

@media screen and ( max-width : 568px ) {

        .example {font-size:20px; {
        }
}
```